# Android Back button with many activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-button

I have a Main-activity that starts a Menu-activity, and then 4 buttons in there: Test-button, Create-button, Result-button and Logout-button.

The first Button test starts  a test-activity and the test-activity starts  a process-activity and the process activity starts a endResult-activity. After the endResult-activity I want to go back to the Menu-activity. I don't know if this is possible or if I have to many activities. I have tried to use finish() after starting new activity and it works; I get back to the Menu-activity, but if I want to do this again it crashes when I try to go to the Test-Activity again.

All answers and tips are much appreciated!

Comment: problem'........................

Comment: You should put the crash output from logcat here so we have a better idea of what went wrong the second time you go to Test-Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would solve it:

Instead of having separate activities for test-activity, process-activity, and endResult-activity, just use one activity with a FrameLayout that you can use to dynamically add fragments.
Change test-activity, process-activity, and endResult-activity to fragments, and use FragmentTransactions to load each one in succession, but don't add to the back stack.

As a result, after the user is finished with endResult-activity, a back click will take them back to MenuActivity.

Comment: OK thank you! I solved it , the problem was an error with doInBackground an Asynctask that I have for collecting data from a wifi-moudule. It was running direct when my activity started so I put a button to controll the Asyntaskt. But thank you for your answer man!

Comment: @Kamin22  Nice, glad you resolved it!  You might want to still consider changing your architecture to how I described.  The way you have it currently has the potential to cause problems once you add more complexity to the code.

Comment: Ok I will look it up, thank you!